# i need a function to initialize this array

Tags: c, initialization

The code should read the result of a race and save them in a struct.
The struct is the same for both stable and pilot, cause in both cases I only need to store points and the name.

The txt it should read is of this type

```
Hamilton mercedes
Bottas mercedes
Verstappen redbull
Norris mclaren
Albon redbull
Perez racingpoint
Leclerc ferrari
Stroll racingpoint
Sainz mclaren
Vettel ferrari
Ricciardo Renault
Gasly alphatauri
ocon renault
Giovinazzi alfaromeo
Kvyat alphatauri
Magnussen haas
Raikkonen alfaromeo
Latifi williams
Grosjean Haas
Russel williams
```

Fixed amount of stable 10 and drivers 20.
In this txt there is only 1 race but the read function is made to be able to read more one after an other.
the name are already oredered base on the result.
the first name is the name of the winner, the second name is the name of the second etc
based on their position they will get points and will be stored in a struct with their points and their name (the points will be added in each race)

Now, I really need a function to initialize the array containing the drivers and the stables, which would be initialize_array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define POSITIONS_WITH_POINTS 10
#define MAX_LINE 50
#define N_PILOTS 20
#define N_TEAM 10

int point_for_position[POSITIONS_WITH_POINTS] = { 
    25, 18, 15, 10,  8, 6, 4, 2,1 
};

struct qualified {
    char  name[MAX_LINE + 1];
    int points;
};

struct qualified *look_for_qualified(struct qualified *array,  int size, char *name)
{
int i = 0;
    for( i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (strcmp(array[i].name, name) == 0)
            return &array[i];
        if(array[i].name[0] == '\0') {
            strcpy(array[i].name,  name);
            array[i].points = 0;
            return &array[i];
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
int read_race(FILE  *fin, struct qualified *pilots,  struct qualified *stable)
{
    char buffer[MAX_LINE + 1];
    int pos;

    char pilot_name[MAX_LINE + 1];
    char stable_name[MAX_LINE +  1];
    int points;

    pos  =  0;

    while( pos < N_PILOTS && 
        fgets(buffer, MAX_LINE +1, fin)  != NULL) {

        /*sscanf(buffer, "%s %s", nome_pilota, nome_scudderia);

        if (pos < POS_A_PUNTI)
            punti = punti_per_pos[pos];
            else
                punti  = 0;  
        */
        struct qualified *pilot = look_for_qualified(pilot, N_PILOTS, pilot_name);
    pilot->points += points;
        struct qualified *stable = 
        look_for_qualified(stable, N_TEAM, stable_name);
    stable->points += points;

    pos++;
    }
    return pos;
}

    initizlize_array()
{

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct qualified pilot[N_PILOTS];
    struct qualified stable[N_TEAM];
    FILE *fin;
    int i;

    if (argc != 2 ) {
        printf(" wrong number of arguments");
        return  1;
    }
    fin = fopen(argv[1], "rt");
    //initizlize_array(pilot, N_PILOTS);
    //initizlize_array(stable, N_TEAM);
    while (read_race(fin, pilot, stable) != 0 ) {

    }
    fclose(fin);
}
```

Comment: _initialize_ in C has a specified usage, the value the object has when it is _defined_ like `int a[] = { 2,3};`.  Here it looks like your want the array to be _assigned_ early in it life..  Is that correct?

Comment: i want to assign neutral values early, yes

Comment: to each of the 10 struct of the list

Comment: i believe it's the way to fix Bus error: 10

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf(" wrong number of arguments");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`. and (in this case) should be informing the user of the correct syntax.  Suggest: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s inputFileName\n", argv[0] );`

Comment: OT: regarding: `fin = fopen(argv[1], "rt");`  when calling C library functions, like `fopen()` should always check for an error.  Suggest: `fin = fopen(argv[1], "rt");  if( ! fin ) { perror( "fopen to read input file failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`  Which will output to `stderr` both your error message AND the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.

Comment: are you saying that running your code results in a bus error?

Comment: regarding: `struct qualified *pilot = look_for_qualified(pilot, N_PILOTS, pilot_name);  pilot->points += points;`  The function: `look_for_qualified()` can return NULL. When that happens, this statement: `pilot->points += points;` will result in a seg fault event.  Similar considerations exist for: `look_for_qualified(stable, N_TEAM, stable_name);
        stable->points += points;`

Comment: regarding: `while( pos < N_PILOTS && 
        fgets(buffer, MAX_LINE +1, fin)  != NULL) {`  the results of the call to `fgets()` is never used.

Comment: regarding: `struct qualified *pilot = look_for_qualified(pilot, N_PILOTS, pilot_name);
        pilot->points += points;
        
        struct qualified *stable = 
        look_for_qualified(stable, N_TEAM, stable_name);
        stable->points += points;`  the arrays: `stable_name[]` and `pilot_name[]` are not initialized however, the function: `look_for_qualified()` is sourcing those arrays when making comparisons.  This is an error